# IE 11 backward compatibility

Tags: css, jsp, internet-explorer, meta-tags

I just added the following meta tag to all my jsp's to force render in the highest possible document mode for the browser.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

It works fine in IE 11. but the struts 2 application gets buggy in previous IE version i.e. IE 10 and IE 8. Many of the alignments are wrong. Unnecessary scrollbars.

The reason i added this meta tag was the application was loading in IE 7 document mode when deployed on a unix box, But it worked fine in my local deployment.

How to achieve compatibility in all IE browser versions.

Comment: Just adding this to your page will not make IE8 behave like IE11. This method can be used as a way to make newer browsers behave like older versions, but IE8 will always render in IE8 mode unless you tell it to render in an older version e.g. IE7.

Comment: I want the application to render in IE 8 mode when opened in IE 8 ,IE 9 mode when opened in IE 9 and so on is that possible somehow.

Comment: Then what you have done should work, providing you have used a doctype  (`<!DOCTYPE html>`). Without a doctype, pages will render in a browsers "quirks mode". Browsers assume that a page without a doctype is very old, and therefore could render better in quirks mode. You should also ensure that the doctype is on the very first line, no white space before at all. In your browser, right click and "view source" to check that its on the first line.

Comment: If you're loading the page from local resources (your hard drive, the corporate network), The x-ua-compatible header is part of the answer.  If you've not changed the default settings, this other part is that your pages may be being loaded in compatibility view by default.  To change this for a given client, change the compatibility settings so that intranet pages aren't automatically loaded into compatibility view.  To change this for a page, add a mark of the web (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628(v=vs.85).aspx).